# What is the probability that out of 8 simultaneously flipped coins, two land on heads

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

> 8 coins are simultaneously flipped. What is the probability that heads are showing on at most 2 of them?

I think we have that our probability is $\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{2} \binom{8}{n}}{\displaystyle2^8},$ but how would I simplify this? Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your answer is correct (assuming it's a fair coin) and there's no need to simplify the answer. Just leave it written the way it is.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you!

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{2} \binom{8}{n} = 9$

Comment: Actually, $\sum_{n = 0}^2 \binom{8}{n} = \binom{8}{0} + \binom{8}{1} + \binom{8}{2} = 1 + 8 + 28 = 37$.